# Specify an MSI Transform via MSI Properties

Tags: windows-installer

I have an MSI transform that I have embedded as a resource in my MSI File, using the WiX binary element. I want to enable people to be able to apply the embedded transform, by specifying the TRANSFORMS property on the MSI.

Using ORCA, I add the TRANSFORMS property, and specify the transform to use. However, it does not appear that the transform actually works. Running with `msiexec /i product.msi /lv log.txt`, I see a line that says

`MSI (c) (0C:FC) [11:27:06:957]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Deleting TRANSFORMS property. Its current value is ':Product.mst'.`

How can I get the MSI to use the transform that I am specifying?

**Edit:** I just tried specifying the TRANSFORMS property manually like this: `msiexec /i Product.msi /lv Log.txt TRANSFORMS=:Transform.mst`, and msiexec complains about not being able to find the transform. Also, if I use 7-Zip to extract the contents of the MSI, the transform is listed as "Transform.binary". Could this be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See:

[_Storages Table (Windows)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372916%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

You won't see this table in ORCA because it's a temp table.  But if you run an SQL query you'll get the names back.  That's what needs to be used in your TRANSFORMS property.